How to stop GitHub CI failure notification emails (only)
How can I stop GitHub from spamming me email notifications about a failed CI job, without stopping all other email notifications?
I own a repo on GitHub that has frequent builds that fail. It's filling my inbox and causing me to miss other actually important notifications.
I still want to receive notifications when:

Someone opens an issue
Someone opens a PR
Someone tags me
Literally every other way that it notifies me now, except when a GitHub Actions build fails

How can I update my GitHub notification settings to suppress only CI build failure notifications?

Rather than trying to disable those specific notification emails, you may find it easier to simply create a rule for them for a specific repository in your email client.
Those specific notification emails will have the address ci_activity@noreply.github.com listed in the message's CC header field.
Excerpts from Filtering email notifications: 

Each email notification that GitHub sends contains header information. The header information in
every email is consistent, so you can use it in your email client to
filter or forward all GitHub notifications, or certain types of GitHub
notifications.



GitHub will CC you if you're subscribed to a conversation. The second
CC email address matches the notification reason. The suffix for these
notification reasons is @noreply.github.com

